# Deploying .Net Apps from a shared directory

Tags: .net, vb.net, deployment, .net-3.5, clickonce

We were planning to use Click Once deployment for a library of applications. Due to the security and political environment of where I work I don't have ability get a web server set up to do this. I have a test app exe sitting out in a shared directory along with the files generated in the release build and it works. I've never programmed where my app was executed from a shared drive. It's always been direct install or web.

Is this an acceptable deployment strategy? where well if it works "it works"?

Comment: Thanks for the tip stakx. I just corrected that. I'm still a relative noob to the site and I have gotten some valuable info from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ClickOnce off a shared drive is a supported option and works well.

I have used this mechanism myself.

See [Publishing ClickOnce Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/748fh114.aspx) on MSDN.

From [How to: Specify the Location Where End Users Will Install From](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c37e68bc.aspx):

> In the Installation URL field, enter the installation location using a fully qualified URL using the format http://www.microsoft.com/ApplicationName, or a **UNC path using the format \Server\ApplicationName**.

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be ok using ClickOnce to deploy install files to a network share.

Running an application (.exe) *directly* from a network share is prone to problems because apps on a network location are less trusted than on your local drives (due to the default policy of the .NET framework which was [fixed in 3.5 SP1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2008/08/13/net-framework-3-5-sp1-allows-managed-code-to-be-launched-from-a-network-share.aspx) and then broken again in 4.0)

If you really want to do the latter you have to [fully trust the share](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/12/30/344554.aspx)